# Include negative values in sum but should not display in highcharts barcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart, dotnethighcharts, gwt-highcharts

I am using highchart barcharts. If we set minimum value to -1000, it displays the negative values on opposite side of y-axis and positive on other side. I am looking for, if it can display only positive, but total sum should include the negative values as well.
For example the graph has
-25,-10,2,35,5

It should show 7 as total and should not display negative values on other side of axis.

Comment: It is not clear what you try to do from your description. Paste your code here or refer to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x1dz8noq/ and provide more details of your goal.

Comment: I have seen your code, It should include negative values in total only and should not display graph bars opposite to y axis.

Comment: How many bars should the chart have? What are -25,-10,2,35,5?

Comment: these are values we will use on graph. -25 and -10 are values and i want them to appear in total only but their bars (opposite in y axis) should not be visible.

Comment: So add them to the rest of points/sum them before you create a chart - don't create bars for them.

Comment: post as answer pls, this may help.